# WebJob gets deployed from Azure DevOps Pipeline but doesn't show up under WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I have a **ASP.NET** MVC WebApp deployed on Azure configured with Azure DevOps and .NET Core WebJob also configured for deployment through Azure Pipeline.

Both WebApp and WebJob get successfully deployed through pipeline.
I can see EXE and other files of my WebJob in :

```
"D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\MyWebJob"
```

through Kudu console.

But, the WebJob doesn't show up in the "WebJob" section of my WebApp on Azure portal.

I can not manually add WebJob through portal, as its source code configured with Azure DevOps. I tried publishing my WebJob through Visual Studio, but that also didn't work.

This is my WebJob YML build section.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/WebJob.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

I've restarted, redeployed both WebApp and WebJob, but no luck!

Comment: Seems like Derek's last sentence answered your concern. resets every time I deploy from DevOps, so you need to change it back every time.  `I tried publishing my WebJob through Visual Studio, but that also didn't work.` And you said it built properly in Azure DevOps, your issue should not related to Azure devops, you could remove redundant azure-devops and azure-pipelines tag.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is the 'correct' way to address this, but I had a similar situation and was able to see my WebJobs by setting the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE application setting to zero.

Keep in mind, this resets every time I deploy from DevOps, so you need to change it back every time.

Comment: I already had "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" set to "0". And, it didn't get reset after multiple deployments. But, why the above way is not 'correct'? I have followed standard Azure documentation.